# Can View content be filtered to what's new since user's last login?

Tags: 7, views, users

We have a View that displays recently created content of a specific custom type – currently, it's showing the titles of the most recent 3 items. The site requires login, so can identify unique individuals. So how might we get this View to display only the items that are new since a particular user's last login? Or is there another way to display such a content list, other than by Views?

Comment: Drupal records the last login time, so it should be possible to do so. I'm not sure if there is any existing contributed module that can does it creating a custom module with a custom views handler that returns the users last login time clause should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, add a new filter criteria for "Content: Has new content." This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I think I had passed over that filter previously because I thought it referred to a particular user's content. In this case we are looking at any new content regardless of creator, and this seems to do it. I also added a No Results message, otherwise the entire View block won't display if there's nothing new to show.

Comment: Excellent! So glad it worked.